# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource in ....\Dynamic\Developer.php:50

Tags: admin, backend, magento2.3.4, dashboard, developer-mode

I have faced below error after upgrade, deploy and compile commands. After logging from magento2 backend in dashboard it's throwing the error. here `Developer mode` is enabled.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class
> Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource in
> vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php:50
> Stack trace: #0
> vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(70):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...')
> #1 vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(167):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framewo...')
> #2 vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(273):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array,
> 'Magento\Framewo...', NULL, 'resource', 'Arguements\...') #3
> vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(236):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolv in
> vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php
> on line 50

Answer (score 0):

I have received this error occasionally when Magento fails to compile all packages properly. Try just running your di:compile and static deployment commands a second time.